# How to multiple all rows of a Pandas dataframe by a single row in another Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have this Dataframe in python[image: df1]

and I want to multiple every row in the first dataframe by this single row in the dataframe below as a vector
[image: df2]

Some things I have tried from googling : df.mul, df.apply. But it seems to multiply the two frames together normally instead of a vectorized operation

Comment: Try `df1 * df2.to_numpy()` ..?

Comment: lol didn't know it was that simple thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3], 'y':[1,2,3]})
v1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[2], 'y':[3]})
```

Multiply DataFrame with row:

```
df.multiply(np.array(v1), axis='columns')
```

Answer (score 0):

If the use case needs accurate matching of columns

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]], columns=['x', 'y'])
coeffs_df = pd.DataFrame([[10, 9]], columns=['y', 'x'])
```

Need to convert the df with single row (`coeffs_df`) to a series first, the perform `multiply`

```
df.multiply(coeffs_df.iloc[0], axis='columns')
```