# How to multiply dataframe by row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hello I am trying to multiply a dataframe with a row from another dataframe.

#### `df1`

| Date | ABC | DEF | XYZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-31 | 3 | 4 | 2 |
| 2020-02-31 | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| 2020-03-31 | 4 | 2 | 6 |
| 2020-04-31 | 2 | 2 | 7 |

#### `df2`

| Year | ABC | DEF | XYZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020 | .5 | .4 | .3 |

Is there a way to multiple DF2 across all values of DF1 to get DF3 like below.

#### `df3`

| Date | ABC | DEF | XYZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-31 | 1.5 | 1.6 | .6 |
| 2020-02-31 | .5 | 1.2 | 1.5 |
| 2020-03-31 | 2 | .8 | 1.8 |
| 2020-04-31 | 1 | .8 | 2.1 |

I have tried

```
df3.loc[:,['ABC','DEF','XYZ']] = df1.mul(df2, level=1,axis='columns')
```

But with that I end up with `df3` being full of NaN.

Comment: `df3 = df1.set_index("Date").mul(df2.to_numpy())`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to multiple all rows of a Pandas dataframe by a single row in another Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60661095/how-to-multiple-all-rows-of-a-pandas-dataframe-by-a-single-row-in-another-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
cols = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'XYZ']
df3 = df1.copy()
df3[cols] = df3[cols].mul(df2[cols].values)
```

Output:

```
>>> df3
          Date  ABC  DEF  XYZ
0  2020-01-31   1.5  1.6  0.6
1  2020-02-31   0.5  1.2  1.5
2  2020-03-31   2.0  0.8  1.8
3  2020-04-31   1.0  0.8  2.1
```

The trick here is to multiply not by `df2[cols]`, but `df2[cols].values`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1.update(pd.DataFrame(df1.set_index('Date').values*df2.set_index('Year').values,columns=df1.iloc[:,-3:].columns))
```

output

```
        Date  ABC  DEF  XYZ
0  2020-01-31  1.5  1.6  0.6
1  2020-02-31  0.5  1.2  1.5
2  2020-03-31  2.0  0.8  1.8
3  2020-04-31  1.0  0.8  2.1
```

How it works

`df1.set_index('Date').values` gives you an array, say array a

`df2.set_index('Year').values` gives you array b

`pd.DataFrame(a*b, columns=,columns=df1.iloc[:,-3:].columns)` gives you a new df

`df1.update(new df),` updates original df

Answer (score 0):

you have to copy df1 before multipling the columns abc,def,xyz by df2.  update the values of those columns with the multiplied value

```
df1="""
Date    ABC DEF XYZ
2020-01-31  3   4   2
2020-02-31  1   3   5
2020-03-31  4   2   6
2020-04-31  2   2   7
"""
df2="""
Year    ABC DEF XYZ
2020    .5  .4  .3
"""

def create_df(df):
    df=df.strip().split('\n')
    df=list(map(lambda x: x.strip().split('\t'),df))
    df=pd.DataFrame(df[1:],columns=df[0])
    return df

df1=create_df(df1)
df1['ABC']=df1['ABC'].astype(float)
df1['DEF']=df1['DEF'].astype(float)
df1['XYZ']=df1['XYZ'].astype(float)
df2=create_df(df2)
df2['ABC']=df2['ABC'].astype(float)
df2['DEF']=df2['DEF'].astype(float)
df2['XYZ']=df2['XYZ'].astype(float)

cols = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'XYZ']
df3 = df1.copy()
df3[cols]=df1[cols].mul(df2[cols].values)
print(df3)
```

output

```
         Date  ABC  DEF  XYZ
0  2020-01-31  1.5  1.6  0.6
1  2020-02-31  0.5  1.2  1.5
2  2020-03-31  2.0  0.8  1.8
3  2020-04-31  1.0  0.8  2.1
```